# How many component can be added under one single module?

Tags: angular

As per doc, Angular app should have mimimum one Module (root) and can have one or more components under one single module.

**What is the maximum number of components can be added under one single module?
Is there any limitation?**

Note: I understand, having more component in single module is not advisable, I am posted this question for knowledge purpose.

Comment: What is the reason of you want to add? and how many module you want to add?

Comment: In my current project we have around 30 plus component under root module, still there are requirements which may required to add 10 plus components. In initial stage we suppose to go with multiple modules but we missed. I am scared is there any limitation to add more component under one module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components under a module are theoretically **Unlimited**.

The main factor which slows down your app / page performance is the use of watchers (data bindings).

Having thousands of watchers (data binding events) only do a heavy negative impact on performance in all aspects.

The Components under a module, only have little impact on page load times and RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only limitation would be the RAM of the machine, compiling the application.
As far as I know, Angular itself does not have a limitation on declared Components.